# broken image while preview an uploaded image using react and express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

the uploading is working fine.But I cant access the image for preview.

```
class uploadMyFile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        file: null,
        fileUrl:null
    };
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
onFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myImage',this.state.file);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    };
    axios.post("/upload",formData,config)
        .then((response) => {
            alert("The file is successfully uploaded");
            console.log(response.data.results.path);
            this.setState({fileUrl:response.data.results.path})
        }).catch((error) => {
    });
}
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div id="App">
        <SideBar pageWrapId={"page-wrap"} outerContainerId={"App"} />
        <div id="page-wrap" >
        <div >
            </div></div>
        <div style={{marginTop:"100px"}}>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <h1>File Upload</h1>
            <input type="file" name="myImage" onChange= {this.onChange} />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            <img src= {this.state.fileUrl}/>
        </form></div></div>
    )}} export default uploadMyFile

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'newapp/public')));
    app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/newapp/public/index.html'));
    });
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads/",
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null,"IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    } });
    const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
    }).single("myImage");

    app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
    console.log("Request ---", req.body);
    console.log("Request file ---", req.file);//Here you get file.
    /*Now do where ever you want to do*/
    if(!err) {
    return res.status(200).json({
            results:req.file
        });
    }
    })
    })
```

server side error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Weboffice PC
>   2\React\react-express-example\newapp\build\index.html'

error on console :

> GET http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/IMAGE-1579084747954.jpg 404
>   (Not Found)

Comment: are you getting your images in /public/uploads/ folder ???

Comment: my server side app is react-express-example.I found the images at react-express-example/public/uploads

Comment: are you having any public/uploads/  folders in your root directory??

Comment: Like I said,my backend app is react-express-example,my front end app is newapp.I have a directory in react-express-example.not in newapp.

Comment: please do console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'newapp/build')) in your server.js before  app.use(express.static(path.join(........... and check your output give right path of your frontend build/index.html

Comment: C:\Users\PC 2\React\react-express-example\newapp\build\ is the console output 
   C:\Users\PC 2\React\newapp\build\index.html is front end

Comment: as you can see both are different. you need to change your static path like  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../newapp/build')));

Comment: I have changed the path as you told me,still i cant access image.

Comment: update your question with updated changes i'll check

Comment: what i did wrong was I created the react app on the same level of express app, while the react app should have been inside express app. I changed that.

Comment: Problem solved right ?

Comment: no, I dont know how to access the uploaded image from the server side, and no preview at all.

Comment: you can visit my github https://github.com/karenaprakash/final-project.git project and refer what you are doing wrong

Comment: from your code  understood that destination of storage has to be on client side rather than server side,it was the mistake here.Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can make any of your folder as static in your server / client using node static method but path should be correct of your folder

Comment: but how should i access it if its stored in server side,

Comment: you can access it like   http://your_server_url/image_name

Comment: but thats not working,

Comment: i have to check your code